# 500 Internal Server Error while using Cloud Firestore in HTTPS Trigger in Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to post a piece of data to a certain location in my Cloud Firestore. The Cloud Function itself is toggled via HTTPS. For the `request.body` I am using the `bodyParser.json` method.

```
notifull.post('/postNote', (request, response) => {

    // grab variables and files from body and query strings
    var subject = request.body.subject;
    var category = request.body.category;
    var subcategory = request.body.subcategory;

    var title = request.body.title;
    var id = request.body.id;
    var userID = request.body.userID;

    // add data to collection
    var referenceString = `${subject}/${category}/${subcategory}/${id}`;

    var reference = admin.firestore().doc(referenceString);

    reference.set({
        "title": title,
        "id": id,
        "userID": userID,
        "timestamp": Date.now(),
        "upvotes": 0
    });


    // update user posts???

});
```

I expect to have a little document in the reference.

Instead what returns is a 500 Internal Server Error.

The error in the the log is "TypeError: admin.firestore is not a function".  I'm using firebase-admin version 4.2.1.

Comment: Are you sure that your variable `reference` is valid?

Answer (score 1):

You're using an old version of firebase-admin.  Firestore support wasn't added until very recently.  Install the latest version:

```
npm install firebase-admin@latest
```

Also, every HTTPS function should return a response to the client for every possible code path, and only after all the work is complete in the function.

```
reference.set({
    "title": title,
    "id": id,
    "userID": userID,
    "timestamp": Date.now(),
    "upvotes": 0
})
.then(() => {
    response.send("OK")
})
.catch(error => {
    response.status(500).send(error)
})
```